# How can I update my external XML file using AS3?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, save

This is my external xml file db.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<character>
    <main hp="50" lvl="1" dmg="5" def="5" exp="100.00" gold="10"/>
</character>
```

In this part I want that the current value of each be updated.

```
function clickLvl(e:MouseEvent):void
{
     trace("lvl is clicked!");

     //increment values - works fine
     _data.main.@lvl = int(_data.main.@lvl) + 1;
     _data.main.@hp = int(_data.main.@hp) + 10;
     _data.main.@dmg = int(_data.main.@dmg) + 5;
     _data.main.@def = int(_data.main.@def) + 5;
     this.lvlDis.text = String(_data.main.@lvl);
     this.hpDis.text = String(_data.main.@hp);
     this.dmgDis.text = String(_data.main.@dmg);
     this.defDis.text = String(_data.main.@def);
     this.expDis.text = String(_data.main.@exp);
     this.goldDis.text = String(_data.main.@gold);

     // save/update the values in .xml
     /* 
         CODE HERE :D
     */

}
```

The values are updating when I run the SWF file but when I close and open it the values aren't save. How can I update/save the value in my xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save a local file using the Flash Player by using `FileReference.save()`. However, this will make the user choose where to save the file, not your code. You won't know where the user saves it, either.

Another option is to save your data to a local `SharedObject`. This won't change the original XML file, but it will let you store and reload data between SWF sessions. Also keep in mind that `SharedObject` data can be cleared by the user pretty easily.

Using AIR you can create an app that can save to local file-system using the `File` and `FileStream` classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can save locally with FileReference class. If you want to save on the server, you need some server side program to do this.